# How to use dcast.data.table with formula as string

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

I want to use cast for a data.table with formula with name of columns as string

My table:

```
c1    c2    c3
1     A     1
1     B     2
1     C     3
2     A1    1
2     B1    2
2     C1    3
```

I want to have result:

```
c1    1    2    3
1     A    B    C
2     A1   B1   C1
```

I could do it with command

`dcast.data.table(dt, c1 ~ c3, value.var = "c2")`

But I want to run dcast in a function which has param of c1 column name as string. For example

```
f1 <- function(d, col_name1, col_name2, col_name3) {
  dcast.data.table(d, col_name1 ~ col_name3, value.var = col_name2)
}
```

So I would call

```
f1(dt, "c1", "c2", "c3")
```

Hope anyone can help!

Comment: What happened to `C1`?

Comment: @zx8754 Sorry for bad question because of my wrong submition. I have edit my question so please remove -1. Thanks!

Comment: I did not vote it down.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`dcast` accepts formula as a string as well.

```
f1 <- function(d, col_name1, col_name2, col_name3) {
    dcast.data.table(d, paste(col_name1, "~", col_name3), value.var = col_name2)
}

f1(dt, "c1", "c2", "c3")
#    c1  1  2  3
# 1:  1  A  B  C
# 2:  2 A1 B1 C1
```

Note that you don't have to load `reshape2` and you can also directly use just `dcast` instead of `dcast.data.table` from versions 1.9.5+